# MVVMCross - Passing Enum as a ConverterParameter

Tags: mvvmcross

I want to pass a specific Enum Value as a ConverterParameter in my Android View.

I am using MvvmCross' MvxBind like this:

```
local:MvxBind="Visibility Person.Status, 
Converter=EqualityToVisibility, ConverterParameter=PersonState.State1"
```

However the value that gets passed into the Converter's Convert method is the string "PersonState.State1" whereas I want the enum value. How do I tell MVVMCross to pass in the enum. XAML markup has the x:static extension but i cannot see an equivalent for Android layouts

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVVCross: Pass an enum value as a CommandParameter for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149547/mvvcross-pass-an-enum-value-as-a-commandparameter-for-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done using the standard value converter and binding syntax. As @Cheesebaron points out in comments, this is similar to the CommandParameter case - see [MVVCross: Pass an enum value as a CommandParameter for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149547/mvvcross-pass-an-enum-value-as-a-commandparameter-for-android)

To achieve the effect you need, I think the easiest route would be to modify your value converter to take and parse a string.

An alternative approach could be to implement a second value converter - `ParsePersonStateValueConverter` - which would just take a string input and would return the parsed `enum`value. You could then nest this with your equality value converter in your binding expression:

```
 local:MvxBind="Visibility EqualityToVisibility(Person.Status, ParsePersonState('State1'))"
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart and Cheesebaron. My interim fix was to Enum.Parse and that does work but I did not want to make the Converter specific to that enum so embedding and Converter into the Converter syntax would let me do that. I will try that later.

Comment: I have had a go at using a Converter for the Parameter. local:MvxBind="Visibility EqualityToVisibility(Person.Status, ParsePersonState('State1'))">. Trouble is the the ParsePersonStateConverter never gets called. Any thoughts?

Comment: It was the classic. I had used left 'Value' in the binding syntax so it could never find the converter i.e. ParsePersonStateVALUE('State1') rather than ParsePersonState('State1'). Idiot.

Answer (score 0):

But of course we can pass an enum as a converter parameter. All it takes is a little helper class, a XAML markup extension:

```
[ContentProperty("Value")]
public sealed class MyEnumExtension : IMarkupExtension {
  public MyEnum Value { get; set; }

  public MyEnumExtension() {
    Value = MyEnum.Default; // change to whatever is your default
  }

  public MyEnum.Extension(MyEnum value) {
    Value = value;
  }

  public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => Value;
  object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
};
```

and in the XAML, just use it with the appropriate namespace where it was defined:

```
< ... {Binding ... ConverterParameter={local:MyEnum AnyMyEnumValue}}" ... />
```

It's important to name the extension class with the exact name of the enum, with the `Extension` suffix appended.

Parsing and conversion will be done at compilation time, the value is stored with strict typing and can be used in the converter directly, without parsing, just casting to the enum:

```
(MyEnum)parameter
```